# Selector > seems not working in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to set an background of color red for all the direct children

the #destinations
but I don't want to set an background for

Paris

because it isn't direct descendent of #destinations

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hijos Directos</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js">

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#destinations > li").css("background-color","red");
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Where do you want to go?</h1>
    <h2>Travel Destinations</h2>
    <p>Plan your next adventure.</p>
    <ul id="destinations">
        <li>Rome</li>
        <li>
            <ul id="france">
                <li>Paris</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Rio</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not` along with `:has` selector to only target li elements that are empty:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#destinations > li:not(:has(ul))").css("background-color","red");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v834L8og/)**

Answer (score 2):

The code is working as expected. The color is being set for the parent li for france which is causing the whole li to be red. The child li is inheriting the background color from the parent li.

Inspect the code in any web browser inspector and see this.

You can try this as a solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/uLfdnzc0/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#destinations > li").css("background-color","red");
    $("#destinations > li > ul").css("background-color","white");
});
```